# How to use addAll() with different types

Tags: java, list, collections, linked-list

I have a course project and I am not able to solve the following problem:

I need to create a linkedlist in which I can add a list of elements from a class called Person, and a list of elements from a class called Accounts using addAll()

```
List<Person> persons= new LinkedList<Person>();
```

```
List<Accounts> accounts= new LinkedList<Accounts>();
```

```
List<???> elements = new LinkedList<>();
```

```
elements.addAll(persons);
elements.addAll(accounts);
```

My teacher ordered to make a class ElementsOfTheBank to fill the place with ???, but I couldn't understand how to make it work :(

Comment: Is there a special reason why it's `Accounts` and not `Account`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a common type that is shared by all elements of the bank. Trivially, `java.lang.Object` is common to them all, but perhaps you're being asked to make e.g. `public interface ElementOfBank`, so that you can then declare your Person class as `class Person implements ElementOfBank {}`.

Once you've done that, you can declare your list to be of that element: `List<ElementOfBank> elements = ...;`, and you could call `.addAll(persons)` on such a list. After all, every person instance is also an ElementOfBank, that's what `class Person implements ElementOfBank` means.

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of bad example, but your teacher probably wants you to use [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

As a person and an account are both "elements of the bank", your classes can look like this:

```
class ElementsOfTheBank {
    // common variables between Person and Account
}

class Person extends ElementsOfTheBank {
    // ...
}

class Account extends ElementsOfTheBank {
    // ...
}
```

Then you can add both types to your list:

```
List<ElementsOfTheBank> elements = new LinkedList<>();
elements.addAll(persons);
elements.addAll(accounts);
```

Comment: Yes. ElementsOfTheBank could also be an interface

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Collections just to combine correlated objects together.

It doesn't make much sense to create a `List<Object>` in order to `Person` and `Account` lists together. Introducing a common super of `Person` and `Account` doesn't seem to be a great idea as well. What is the advantage of binding through Inheritance a physical person and a bank account? I would rather suggest establishing the relationship between a person and their accounts through Composition (not Inheritance).

The better option would be to create a `class`, let's say `Bank`. That would encapsulate the two lists. I.e. you can introduce behavior for managing bank-clients and their accounts, and bank instance would become a single entry point for all operation you need to perform with them.

```
public class Bank {
    private List<Person> persons= new LinkedList<>();
    private List<Accounts> accounts= new LinkedList<>();

    // constructors, getters
    
    public boolean createAccount() {
        // TO DO ...
        return ...;
    }

    public Person findPerson(SomeProperty id) {
        // TO DO ...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: For a real life project, you are right. But this is an artificial exercise for newbies that should most probably learn inheritance and polymorphism through it. In that respect, your answer is wrong, or at least not helpful.

Comment: @tquadrat The Answers on SO a meant to bring **Value** to the **Readers** (not only to OP). You've admitted the logic is correct, how the answer is not helpful. Secondly, Collection-abuse is a very common antipattern among beginners, none can really understand OO, if they are not able to recognize that a set of properties should constitute an Object. That's an essential Class-design, not an enterprise development It seems like you've missed the point, of what I was talking about. If I may, I would kindly suggest to avoid making opinionated comments (did you so OP's assignment requirements?).

Comment: Nice to read about opinionated comments under an opinion based answer. Nobody would have complained about your "answer" if you really had provided an answer to question and *afterwards* came up with you sermon on proper design and collection-abuse (see the answer from  7evy on how this could look like). And by the way, that sermon is wasted to the questioner, because he just just forwarded the poorly designed question from his teacher/instructor/professor to us.

Comment: So your vote should signify that this answer has no value? I would appreciate if you would provide a constructive criticism instead of talking on behalf OP.